# How can I get the earliest date based on the current value in a column?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am using SQL via Oracle. For each EMPLOYEE, I am trying to return the DATE on which they first were placed in their most recent POSITIONCODE. My table looks like this:

| EMPLOYEE | POSITIONCODE | DATE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| DAVE | SW001 | 01/01/2023 |
| DAVE | SW001 | 12/08/2022 |
| DAVE | WB566 | 12/01/2021 |
| JENNY | XD234 | 01/15/2023 |
| JENNY | MX124 | 12/12/2022 |

The results I am expecting:

| EMPLOYEE | POSITIONCODE | DATE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| DAVE | SW001 | 12/08/2022 |
| JENNY | XD234 | 01/15/2023 |

I have tried certain variations of self-joins, group by, min, etc.. I keep getting rows of data that group the most recent value for each EMPLOYEE and POSITIONCODE combination (this returns more than one value for each EMPLOYEE). I only need one value for each EMPLOYEE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Oracle 12, you can use `MATCH_RECOGNIZE`. This will also detect whether the employee has switched from a position to another position and then back to the first position and will retrieve the earliest date for the latest occurrence of that final position:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
MATCH_RECOGNIZE(
  PARTITION BY employee
  ORDER BY "DATE" DESC
  MEASURES
    FIRST(positioncode) AS positioncode,
    LAST("DATE") AS earliest_date
  PATTERN ( ^ same_position+ )
  DEFINE
    same_position AS FIRST(positioncode) = positioncode
)
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (EMPLOYEE, POSITIONCODE, "DATE") AS
SELECT 'DAVE',  'SW001', DATE '2023-01-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'DAVE',  'SW001', DATE '2022-12-08' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'DAVE',  'WB566', DATE '2021-12-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'JENNY', 'XD234', DATE '2023-01-15' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'JENNY', 'MX124', DATE '2022-12-12' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'ALICE', 'AB123', DATE '2022-01-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'ALICE', 'DE456', DATE '2022-01-02' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'ALICE', 'AB123', DATE '2022-01-03' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'ALICE', 'AB123', DATE '2022-01-04' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| EMPLOYEE | POSITIONCODE | EARLIEST_DATE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ALICE | AB123 | 2022-01-03 00:00:00 |
| DAVE | SW001 | 2022-12-08 00:00:00 |
| JENNY | XD234 | 2023-01-15 00:00:00 |

---

In earlier versions, you can use multiple comparisons of the `ROW_NUMBER` analytic function:

```sql
SELECT employee,
       positioncode,
       "DATE"
FROM   (
  SELECT employee,
         positioncode,
         "DATE",
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY employee ORDER BY "DATE" ASC) AS dt_rn
  FROM   (
    SELECT t.*,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY employee ORDER BY "DATE" DESC)
             AS rn,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
             PARTITION BY employee, positioncode ORDER BY "DATE" DESC
           ) AS pc_rn
    FROM   table_name t
  )
  WHERE  rn = pc_rn
)
WHERE  dt_rn = 1;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/bddqes_z)

Answer (score 3):

You can use common table expression with `row_number()over()` and `min()over()` window functions to achieve this result:

Query:

```
with cte as
(
  select Employee,PositionCode,Dates,row_number()over(partition by Employee order by dates desc)rn,
         min(dates)over(partition by Employee,POSITIONCODE)minDates from empTable
)
select Employee,PositionCode,minDates Dates from cte where rn=1
```

Output:

| EMPLOYEE | POSITIONCODE | DATES |
| --- | --- | --- |
| DAVE | SW001 | 08-DEC-22 |
| JENNY | XD234 | 15-JAN-23 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/r3rCJpuj)

Comment: This works for the sample data, but it's not clear to me if/how OP wants to handle the case where employees switch to the position multiple times. If employees can switch between positions many times, this will show the _first_ time they switched to their current position, even if they held other positions in between. (This might be desirable; just pointing it out).

Comment: I did not think of that. I would be looking for the most recent time an employee switch to their current position.